# Where can I modify the way woocomerce displays the product's additional information?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm working on a site for a client selling used cars, they have a list of statuses of how good different components of the car are. e.g: Tires: Worn, transmission: OK.

I just added these fields as attributes (the ones that show in the additional information tab)
We want to show those values in a more graphical way, with images and highlighted text depending on those attributes, I have the code ready for that.

Where can I modify the template to add this in? Or can you point me in the right direction of how I can achieve this?

Comment: First read: [Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/) then the related template to edit is [single-product/tabs/additional-information.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.3.0/templates/single-product/tabs/additional-information.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use [ACF | Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) it is free, has alot of features and constantly updated, you also have alot of documentation for the plugin.

In your case I would use field [select](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/select/).

Also depends how much fields do you have, but I belive this is the way to go.
You can do then call the fields that you created and output your logic via PHP.

```
<p>Tires: <?php the_field('tires'); ?></p>
```

And If you want to custom code those attributes in the end here is the PHP that you can put in the template file and modify it.

```
<?php $attributes = $product->get_attributes();?>
    <table class="shop_attributes">
        <?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) : ?>
            <tr>
                <th style="text-align: left; padding-right: 20px"><?php echo wc_attribute_label( $attribute->get_name() ); ?></th>
                        <td style="text-align: left;">
                            <?php
                            $values = array();

                            if ( $attribute->is_taxonomy() ) {
                                $attribute_taxonomy = $attribute->get_taxonomy_object();
                                $attribute_values = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), $attribute->get_name(), array( 'fields' => 'all' ) );

                                foreach ( $attribute_values as $attribute_value ) {
                                    $value_name = esc_html( $attribute_value->name );

                                    if ( $attribute_taxonomy->attribute_public ) {
                                        $values[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $attribute_value->term_id, $attribute->get_name() ) ) . '" rel="tag">' . $value_name . '</a>';
                                    } else {
                                        $values[] = $value_name;
                                    }
                    }
                } else {
                    $values = $attribute->get_options();

                    foreach ( $values as &$value ) {
                        $value = make_clickable( esc_html( $value ) );
                    }
                }

            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values );
                            ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: They’re about 20 fields

Comment: I prefer custom fields as they are easier control both for code vise and user interface.
It's up to you what you want to do in the end :)

Comment: Which template file is that in your example?

Comment: You can modify woocommerce/single-product.php with this and place your own way of attributes

Comment: Here is some introduction to Woocommerce themeing https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/

Comment: Just tried it this is great! Can I use those fields in the product list as well?

Comment: Sorry wrong comment, yes you can use those fields in every page as long as you have the ID's of product's that are attached or while is in the query loop.